# word use vba to create a hyperlink from clipboard

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have copied a hyperlink into the clipboard.
In a Word docx I have selected some text and want to convert the text to be a hyperlink to the data on the clipboard.

I can manually do this by right-clicking the selected text, selecting Link-> and either clicking the item from recent links, or selecting Link-> then Insert Link and pasting the clipboard into the address.

I would like to do this in a macro that I can assign to a key as a shortcut. E.g., copy the link to the clipboard in another program then in Word press a single key to have the selected text become a hyperlink to the address on the clipboard.

Comment: Use the macro recorder to record yourself while adding the link through the right-click menu and then look at the generated code.

Comment: For the clipboard part, you can use [`DataObject` and `GetFromClipboard` and `GetText`](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/ManipulateClipboard.htm) to read the contents of the clipboard, and use that instead of the status link you pasted while recording the macro.

Comment: Thank you. It took some work to get the DataObject and link working,

Answer (score 1):

Thanks CherryDT, Here is the final VBA:

```vb
Sub AddHyperLink()
'
' AddHyperLink Macro
'
' 20-Apr-20
' Converts the selected test into a hyperlink
' The URL must be in the clipboard
'
'

    Dim MyData As DataObject
    Dim strAddr As String
    Dim strTitle As String

    Set MyData = New DataObject
    MyData.GetFromClipboard
    strAddr = MyData.GetText

    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Copy
    MyData.GetFromClipboard

    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:=strAddr _
        , SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=Selection.Range
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think `Selection.Copy` and the second `MyData.GetFromClipboard` in the next line do anything now though, you could try removing them!